# .htaccess Php rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I try to realize a system of rewriting URLs in .htaccess.

Then here is my goal:
If I have an url of this form: `http://localhost/view.php?Id=456`

Then I want to transform it to: `http://localhost/456`

I use this rule in htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^ ([a-zA-Z0-9] +) $ view.php? Id = $ 1`

Now this works very well!

But my problem I want to add points to id ie instead of 456 I can put: my.book

That is to say: `http://localhost/my.book`

Comment: you just need to change reg-x pattern to allow periods, or perhaps just everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before the `RewriteRule` line to tell the server that the `RewriteRule` written below to be executed if the input passed in the URL is not an actual file. Because server searches for a file matching the input you pass in the URL and also it won't work in case you pass `my.book` in the URL since web server recognizes `.` as prefix for extension like `.php` or `.html` or like so and thereby it results in `Not Found` error if there is no file named `my.book` exists. So, you also need to escape `.` in the URL.

To allow `.`'s in the input, you need to add `.` with escape sequence `\` in the character class group like `^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$`. Note, allowing this can result in escaping the extension in the URL, that is, passing `view.php` in the URL won't navigate to the actual file. Rather, it will be considered as a value in the query string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support
It worked very well!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer worked for you, feel free to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$ view.php?Id=$1
```

Basically what I did is I added `\.` with your pattern. This will make sure your regex matches any letter (small/caps), decimal numbers and periods (`.`). Hope this helps :)

Comment: That won't work. Also not helpful as you're not explaining what's going on. Instead, you could take 10 seconds to post "why" (explain the regex) as well as the correct solution (hint: remove the spaces). Then the OP won't need to post here again, and other people searching for answers can learn.

Comment: @Robbie updtaed

Comment: Thanks. More helpful!